# c# client-server List of objects cast error

Tags: c#, list, serialization, casting

I am developing a client server application in C#.

I am sending from my server to client an `List` of `Students` objects which I serialize on the server side and deserialize on client side. The serialization and deserialization are as follows :

```
// server side serialization.
List<Student> ordByMedGen = repo.ordByMedGen();
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, ordByMedGen);

// client side deserialization.
BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
List<Student> list = (List<Student>)bin.Deserialize(receive.BaseStream);
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
// print the list
```

Using this method I succesfully send a `List` of Strings from server side and printed on the client side. When I tried with my `Student` class I got the following error

> [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ServerClient.Student] cannot be
>   cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ServerClient.Student]. 
>   Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at
>   location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at
>   location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

To create the Server.exe and Client.exe I used the following commands:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Server.cs Repository.cs Student.cs
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Client.cs Student.cs
```

and I get no errors or warning.
Also my `Student` class have the `[Serialization]` attribute.
I did searched the web for this kind of errors but i couldn't find anything usefull.

Later Edit: Maybe at compilation the fact that Student.cs is provided as a reference both on Server and Client somehow confuse the compiler and sees Student as 2 different types as in error: A and B ?

Later Edit(2): This problem can be also solved by creating at compilation an dll for 
Student.cs and referenced on server and client, so the compiler doesen't get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two different assemblies - one at the client, one on the server - contributing this type. Types are defined by their assembly, and even if identical: are not interchangeable. Basically, BinaryFormatter will fight you every step of the way here. My advice: don't use BinaryFormatter. Most other serializers (XmlSerializer, json.jet, jil, DataContractSerializer, protobuf-net etc) will work perfectly fine in your scenario, and will not complain at all.

Comment: I changed to XmlSerializer and works just fine. Thank you very much!